# Champion, with a smirk

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The answer to this puzzle is a 16-letter sentence. Good luck!

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Text version of the letter grids:

```
 ERETILUI UEUSTIRE BIRACACL
 ITURERRQ RNQTRANI RLERECBI
 SQETQAIP QSIEUSEQ ECRLAECL
 ALTULUEI ARIRTSIA ABLIBCIB
 NEIQEATL UTQNEANU RBEKKERC
 CAQLALRC SSIRNSUT NKTARUIT
 NEUTIUQA QNTKPLRI IRCNSKCL
 ARURATLI ASULQMAU ICAKRCAE
 
 RHRPEDPR YOLPEHNH AIMRIRTP
 SEPSDSHH LNGGHOLY EORIONGR
 REPRSDDS XGLHLNOX GTENMEOI
 PEHERHSH EYXWXAGP TNMENOTE
 FIATKTOA UHNLGLWW MORIMOEN
 PSREPSHD WGXYOYGO OEGRGMNG
 RDRSREHR EOHWLOLX IMNTOTRM
 DEDSHSRE UNGEWNOI UTRITNTU
```

Comment: Do you happen to have a text version of the letter grids?

Comment: No, I don't. But I can fix that. Will not be online for a while though. So will have to do it later then.

Comment: I can't for the *life* of me figure out a way to find a starting position. There's one *game* especially suited for this kind of grid and those correct squares, but in that game, the previous position cannot be uniquely determined from the current position on the grid, so I guess I'll just have to wait and see if someone can figure this out.

Comment: @Bass Your wish is my command ;-) In all honesty, your remark here about a 'game' suddenly helped me make sense of the 'odd ones out' I had previously found (and got totally stuck thinking about), so thank you for providing the spark!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing to do is work out what shape each diagram represents. Across each row, these are in turn:

> EQUILATERAL TRIANGLE, UNIT SQUARE, BLACK CIRCLE,
>  RED SPHERE, YELLOW HEXAGON, GREEN TETROMINO.

Next:

> Highlight the cells in each grid which contain **letters that do not appear in the name of the corresponding shape**:
>
>  [image: Highlighted squares of unused letters]

What do we now have? The highlighted cells on these 8x8 grids of squares:

> Are the squares on a chessboard that represent **the furthest a chess piece can (theoretically) move from its starting position**! We can see this more clearly by highlighting the start positions for the pieces in question (thereby fulfilling the enigmatic Step 1 of the puzzle instructions):
>
>  [image: Chess pieces highlighted]

Now, we have identified 16 letters of interest - the same number as the number of "+/-" commands in Step 2 of the puzzle instructions. What we must do next, therefore, is:

> Augment the letters in our 16 yellow squares by the number of alphabet positions indicated in the command list, like so:
>
>  U-18, T-18, Q-12, C+0, A+10, R-5, D-3, R+2, S-14, R+1, E+4, H+10, R-9, E+18, U-12, U-7

...which then spells out the message we seek (punctuation added)...

> **CHECKMATE, SIR - I WIN!** - a remark fit for a gloating '*champion, with a smirk*', as per the title!

Comment: Well done! I was thinking of adding a suitable hint, guess I don't need to now :)